# Creating dictionary from list with different orders

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

Let's say I have a list that looks like this:

```
[[('name', 'n1')], [('value', 'v1')], [('name', 'n2')], [('value', 'v2')], [('name', 'n3')], [('value', 'v3')]]
```

I am able to run the `res = dict((str(x[0][1]), y[0][1]) for x, y in zip(new[::2], new[1::2]))` where `res` then equals
`{'n1':'v1', 'n2':'v2', 'n3':'v3'}`, which is exactly what I want in this case. This is the case when the names and values alternate.

However, I also have some lists that look like this:

```
[[('name', 'n1')], [('name', 'n2')], [('name', 'n3')], [('value', 'v1')], [('value', 'v2')], [('value', 'v3')]]
```

Here, I have name, name, name followed by the corresponding value, value, value. In this case, I would like to end up with the same `res` dictionary as above, but the code I had would not work properly on this case.

Is there a way I could cover both cases to create a dictionary that maps the names to the corresponding values? (FYI: there might not be three of each each time, it could be more/less).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible one-line solution (`lst` is your input list):

```
res = dict(zip([el[0][1] for el in lst if el[0][0] == 'name'],
               [el[0][1] for el in lst if el[0][0] == 'value']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, quite simple but it wont work when you have odd values.

```
values = [y[1] for x in input_list for y in x]
res = {values[i]: values[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(values), 2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code in 2 steps with a more readable syntax, the only condition is that the 1st occurence of name matche the 1st occurence of value, same for 2nd, 3rd and so on ..
This can be like this :

```
a = <one of the 2 sets of data>
a1 = filter(lambda x: x[0][0]=='name',a) # filter the keys
a2 = filter(lambda x: x[0][0]=='value',a) # filter the values
res = {k[0][1]:v[0][1] for (k,v) in zip (a1,a2)} # mix them into a dict
```